# Highcharts-How to Update Column stacking

Tags: highcharts

I have plot Highcharts with stacked column with stack in each series data graph plot with answer of a Question against two `location` ,set stack as `location.graph` plot with answer are "Parent,patient,Guardian,Family Member,other".

I try to update column stacking to null but is not working.

But the same data i draw with stacking 'normal' [it work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/3t1rvyh2/1/)

But i can't update the series the [issued link](http://jsfiddle.net/m0o85f7e/4/)

Comment: please post your code up to u r tired

Comment: @Thennarasu plz click on the links provided

Comment: Could you add some punctuation to your question? I have read this twice and still I don't understand what is the desired output. Do you mean broken button event? Make sure you are updating series from the last one to the newest one, otherwise it may happen you try to update non existing series: http://jsfiddle.net/m0o85f7e/5/

Comment: @pawel 
Could you plz send  the above comments as  answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update series starting from the last in the array, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m0o85f7e/5/

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
        s = chart.series,
        sLen = s.length;

    while(sLen--) {
        s[sLen].update({
            stacking: ''
        }, false);
    }
    chart.redraw();
});
```